# Unexpected OutOfMemoryException in SessionStateItemCollection Deserialize

Tags: c#

I have an XY-problem. I'm currently trying to learn and understand what's going on with Y itself. To reproduce my scenario, create a new Console Application with this code (and a reference to System.Web 4.0):

```
var badData = new byte[] { 66, 97, 100, 32, 68, 97, 116, 97 };

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(badData))
using (var br = new BinaryReader(ms))
{
    var item = SessionStateItemCollection.Deserialize(br); // <-- OOMException here
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Again, I realize, there is all sorts of problems with this code, but before I go back to X and/or start fixing the actual problems, I'd like to *understand* why the `OutOfMemoryException` occurs.

I've tried to answer my own question, first with common sense, but I can think of no reason why said code would consume a lot of memory?

So next I've tried to answer my question by looking at the call stack, which is:

> ```
> mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.ArrayList.ArrayList(int capacity) + 0x1f bytes    
> System.dll!System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.Reset(int capacity) + 0x21 bytes   
> System.Web.dll!System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Deserialize(System.IO.BinaryReader reader) + 0x75 bytes 
> ConsoleApplication1.exe!ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 20 + 0x9 bytes   C#
> ```

So I check out [the source of `System.Collections.ArrayList`'s relevant constructor](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,72) with this code:

```
public ArrayList(int capacity) {
     if (capacity < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("capacity", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_MustBeNonNegNum", "capacity"));
     Contract.EndContractBlock();

     if (capacity == 0)
         _items = emptyArray;
     else
         _items = new Object[capacity];
}
```

It does *not* throw `OutOfMemoryException`.

Why is that exception occurring (with that call stack) nonetheless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the serialized nature of this object if you look into SessionStateItemCollection.Deserialize method you will find following code:

```
int count = reader.ReadInt32();
...
new SessionStateItemCollection.KeyedCollection(count)
```

In your case count is equal to 543449410, this is over 2 GB of memory in one chunk.